# XAML Designed not showing (Visual Studio 2022)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

So recently I wanted to make a WPF application in C# using Visual Studio 2022.
After creating the project name, .NET core (7.0), I was greeted by this screen:
[image]

On the right hand side, I see the Solution Explorer and Properties. On left I see the toolbox. But how come in the middle, I only see the XAML editor and not the XAML designer like:
[image]

I tried the control `Shift + F7` but that just makes my tabs go from:
[image]

to [image]

I have this in `Tools > Options > Web form Designer`:

[image]

I tried Enabling Web Live Preview instead and nothing changed

In `Tools > Options > XAML Designer` I have:
[image]

If anyone knows why I can't see the XAML Designer, I'd appreciate it :D